# Combine repetitive dictionary in a python list of dictionaries to remove repetition

Tags: python, django, dictionary

**I want to c join this repetitive dictionaries in my list to remove repetiton:**

***The dict:***

```
[{"name": "healthcheck","responseTime": 0.600845,"dateCreated": "11/06/19  13:44"},
{"name": "Stack Overflow","responseTime": 0.849753,"dateCreated": "11/06/19  13:44"},
{"name": "Sample Endpoint","responseTime": 0.559156, "dateCreated": "11/06/19  13:44"},
{"name": "healthcheck", "responseTime": 0.369526,"dateCreated": "11/06/19  08:04"},
{"name": "Stack Overflow","responseTime": 0.928371,"dateCreated": "11/06/19  08:04"},
{"name": "Sample Endpoint","responseTime": 0.535189,"dateCreated": "11/06/19  08:04"}]
```

***Expected dict:***

```
[
 {"name": "healthcheck","responseTime": [0.600845, 0.369526],"dateCreated": ["11/06/19  13:44","11/06/19  08:04"]},
 {"name": "Stack Overflow","responseTime": [0.849753,0.928371],"dateCreated": ["11/06/19  13:44","11/06/19  08:04"] },
 {"name": "Sample Endpoint","responseTime": [0.559156, 0.535189] "dateCreated": ["11/06/19  13:44","11/06/19  08:04"]}
]
```

Comment: Is this JSON you're wanting to combine?

Comment: No its a dictionary key value sometimes it is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume your data is python Dictionary (because I am confused what it is):

```
l = [{"name": "healthcheck","responseTime": 0.600845,"dateCreated": "11/06/19  13:44"},
{"name": "Stack Overflow","responseTime": 0.849753,"dateCreated": "11/06/19  13:44"},
{"name": "Sample Endpoint","responseTime": 0.559156, "dateCreated": "11/06/19  13:44"},
{"name": "healthcheck", "responseTime": 0.369526,"dateCreated": "11/06/19  08:04"},
{"name": "Stack Overflow","responseTime": 0.928371,"dateCreated": "11/06/19  08:04"},
{"name": "Sample Endpoint","responseTime": 0.535189,"dateCreated": "11/06/19  08:04"}]
```

Here a snippet that build your desired dictionary:

```
result = {}
for row in l:
    if row["name"] in result:
      result[row["name"]]["dateCreated"].append(row["dateCreated"])
      result[row["name"]]["responseTime"].append(row["responseTime"])
    else:
      result[row["name"]] = {
          "name": row["name"],
          "dateCreated": [row["dateCreated"]],
          "responseTime": [row["responseTime"]]     
      }

print(list(result.values()))
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'healthcheck', 'dateCreated': ['11/06/19  13:44', '11/06/19  08:04'], 'responseTime': [0.600845, 0.369526]}, {'name': 'Stack Overflow', 'dateCreated': ['11/06/19  13:44', '11/06/19  08:04'], 'responseTime': [0.849753, 0.928371]}, {'name': 'Sample Endpoint', 'dateCreated': ['11/06/19  13:44', '11/06/19  08:04'], 'responseTime': [0.559156, 0.535189]}]
```

But of-course this can be done in more generic way, but I tried to make the solution naive.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `pandas` dataframe instead of a dictionary to represent your data. I edited your dictionary to the proper format, as it looks like you had a list instead. I also converted your `responseTime` values from integers to strings, so they could be properly concatenated with commas in the `join` method. I used the `groupby()` method to group duplicate keys into single records and the `agg()` method to aggregate/concatenate the values:

```
import pandas as pd

myDict = {"name": ["healthcheck", "Stack Overflow", "Sample Endpoint", "healthcheck", "Stack Overflow", "Sample Endpoint"],
          "responseTime": ["0.600845", "0.849753", "0.559156", "0.369526", "0.928371", "0.535189"],
          "dateCreated": ["11/06/19  13:44", "11/06/19  13:44", "11/06/19  13:44", "11/06/19  08:04", "11/06/19  08:04", "11/06/19  08:04"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(myDict)
print(df.groupby("name").agg({'responseTime':', '.join, 'dateCreated':', '.join}))
```

**Output:**

```
     name              responseTime                  dateCreated
Sample Endpoint     0.551956, 0.535189     11/06/19  13:44, 11/06/19  08:04
Stack Overflow      0.849753, 0.928371     11/06/19  13:44, 11/06/19  08:04
healthcheck         0.600845, 0.369526     11/06/19  13:44, 11/06/19  08:04
```

Comment: I think suggesting using Pandas for a beginner and for a simple task, is not quit good idea, but still you may refer to pandas in your answer .

Comment: Let me try getting the data  using panda

Answer (score -1):

```
# Assign the variable for values

method_type = []
time_in_sec = []
date_time = []

for i,j,k in data_1, data_2, data_3:
    method_type.append(i)
    time_in_sec.append(j)
    date_time.append(k)
    dict_data= {{"name": method_type, "responseTime": time_in_sec ,"dateCreated":date_time}}

print(dict_data)
```